# workflow that checks if item is new or modified

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I'm trying to create a workflow that starts automatically (simply sends an email) when an item is created (that part is easy), but will also send an email on certain conditions when modified (when box is checked for update)...

I thought I could check both the `Start Automatically ... item is created` and `Start Automatically ... item is modified` and setup a condition that checks "is item new? if so send email" and another condition for "if update box is checked, send email".

However I need to be able to know if the list item is new.  Essentially I need a workflow to send an email if either of the following conditions are true.

- New Item
- Modified with "update" box checked.

Is there a way to simply check if an item is new?  If not, what would be an good equivalent way to handle this?  I'm trying to stay simple (new to Sharepoint), just using Sharepoint Designer.

Comment: For my use I've gone ahead and used a 2nd workflow, though I might eventually try the method Robin suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 workflow. One when item is created and another when item is updated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the same workflow if you'd like. Just check if the created date is equal to the modified date - if they're the same, then it's just been created. If they're different, you're running in Modified mode.

Comment: I have two SP2013 workflows, both of which are marked as "Manual". As they trigger, the workflow column changes to the current stage. The "modified" date becomes > the created date. ***tl;dr this doesn't work in SharePoint 2013/Online.***

Answer (score 0):

As Jonata has suggested, you can create 2 workflows.

In first workflow, you can select "Start Automatically when item is created". So whenever new item added this workflow will trigger.

In Second workflow, you can select "Start Automatically when item is modified". So whenever item is updated this workflow will trigger. Here you can check the condition where update check box is checked and send mail accordingly.

Hope this helps.