# Email Alerts with dynamic subject on add and edit items to the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, email, modified, item-added

I want to send email alert with dynamic subject

1. When a new item is added ,the subject of the email alert must be 'New item added'.
2. When i edit that item,the subject of the email should be 'Item Modified'

How can i achieve this in a single workflow

i have checked the condition
if currentItem:created equals currentItem:modified
then email_message(a new variable) will be 'New Item Added'
else
email_message will be Item Modified

Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: If you're using MS Flow/PowrAutomate, you can easily accomplish this by:if(equals(triggerOutputs()?['body/Created'], triggerOutputs()?['body/Modified']), 'New Item Added', 'Item Modified')

Comment: What is the version of SharePoint you are using? Online or on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

That would be the default behavior if you select both "created" and "changed" in *Start Options*.

See a similar post here: [workflow that checks if item is new or modified.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138119/workflow-that-checks-if-item-is-new-or-modified/138123)

So if you plan to write the actions in one SharePoint Designer workflow, the workflow will be triggered on new item creation only the first time, and on item modification for the rest of times.